# is "y1 < x < y2" an inequality or inequalities?

Tags: word-choice, plural-forms

I know that *x > y1* is an inequality but I am in doubt over whether *y1 < x < y2* is an inequality or inequalities. Which is right? I think that it may be a math question, but I will be thankful if anyone answers it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As it says in [this College Algebra book](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=y0oXh2GunvIC&pg=PA102&dq=%22a%20simultaneous%20inequality%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=pPeVU_qEKYPrPN_3gPgB&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22a%20simultaneous%20inequality%22&f=false)...

> An inequality of the form
>    **a < x < b**
>    is sometimes referred to as a ***simultaneous inequality***.

We're obviously dealing with domain-specific terminology, but I personally (not a mathematician) wouldn't call **a = b = c** "equalities" - since it's a single expression, I'd say it's an "equality". But we're not exactly talking standard English here, whether it's singular or plural (most people would probably just say it's an "equation" and leave it at that).

Comment: You'd be right. It's a single statement (ie. expression), so it's _an_ inequality.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: I've no idea whether your example is a "more typical" one than OP's, but that's hardly relevant. In fact, I don't consider it particularly relevant whether my cited "College Algebra Book" is completely wrong to use the term at all for their example, since that's just Off Topic domain-specific terminology. So far as I'm concerned, the only issue being addressed here is whether ***inequality*** should be pluralised simply because there are ***two*** "less than" signs. That book agreed with my (non-specialist) natural inclinations, so I cited them.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, My last comment wasn't worded the best.  I'm going to post another one and this one will be deleted.

Comment: I'm going to object to this answer (despite it being selected correct) as too heavy in denying the plural. It's **a mathematical statement** called **a compound inequality** that contains **two inequalities**. My prior sentence used both singular and plural forms to talk about it just fine. It all depends on what perspective one wants to take in talking about the mathematical statement. (A group of people **is** allowed to sit together. Four people **are** allowed to sit together. Depending on how you want to look at it, you can think of it as a **single group** or as **four people**.)

Comment: I'm not sure I've exactly come down "heavily" on this one. I make the point that it's a *personal* opinion, from a *non-mathematician*, and further temper it with *"I **would** say"* (by implication, *if pressed*). Not to mention which I say it's *domain-specific terminology*, and ***not** standard English*. I doubt I could get any more caveats in and still appear to be saying anything at all. I'll just say my preference is from my maths teacher decades ago, who always called [two equations like this](http://studymaths.co.uk/topics/linearSimultaneousEquations.php) ***a** simultaneous equation*

Comment: As your prior comment, "the only issue being addressed here is whether inequalities should be pluralised simply because there are two 'less than' signs". It's a matter of semantics: one can view a (collective) thing as singular or plural depending on what perspective one wants (or needs) to take.  Even in your own sentence, *"a maths teacher...who sometimes [not 'always' check your reference] called **two equations** like this **a simultaneous equation**".* You used both the **plural** and the **singular** to refer to the very same mathematical statement. Both can be used.  I'm just sayin.

Comment: @CoolHandLouis: You're preaching to the converted re "circumstances alter cases" for singular/plural. I'm fed up to the back teeth with others of your fellow countrymen telling me on ELU that ***a** company* or ***a** family* can only accept a singular verb. I don't get your *sometimes/always* point though. I obviously can't remember for certain what my teacher said every single time nearly half a century ago, but I meant *always*, even if the citation in my answer (for a different referent) used *sometimes*.

Comment: (and I did take care to check that my above *two equations like this* link did indeed use that singular form themselves).

Answer (score 0):

This is technically called a [compound inequality](https://www.google.com/search?q=compound+inequality).  Considering the following:

> **Statement 1:** y1 < x < y2.

It's a mathematical statement called a compound inequality that contains two inequalities. My prior sentence used both singular and plural forms to talk about it just fine. How one talks about it depends on one's intent. One may use the singular to focus on the statement as a whole, or one may use a plural form to focus on individual elements:

- "The compound inequality described in Statement 1 is a common form in hydraulics...".
- "The inequalities described in Statement 1 highlight the relationships that x has with y1 and y2..."

Similarly, "The dance group **is** allowed to sit together" and "the four people **are** allowed to sit together". Depending on how you want to look at it, you can think of it as a single group or as four people.

---

I recently needed to describe something just like this at [this answer](https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/26869/3796) where I had originally said **"compound inequality"** in order to sound like **Mr. Proper Math Guy**, but then remembered seeing your question here. So I changed it to "inequalities" just for fun for this question and the plural form sounds just fine to the average person.

- The sentence can be simplified as follows: SOMETHING must have been COMPLETED within two years of FUTURE_DATE. Without getting into the verb tenses (maybe someone can comment), one should see that the following **inequalities** must be true:<sup>1</sup>

  `FUTURE_DATE >= DateOf(SOMETHING,COMPLETED) >= FUTURE_DATE - 2 YEARS`

<sup>1. More proper would be, "...the following **compound inequality** must be true...".</sup>

---

**Note 1:** There certainly are multiple inequalities expressed within a compound inequality.

**Note 2:** A compound inequality can always be expressed as two or more simultaneous inequalities, but the opposite is not true.  In other words, a compound inequality is a simple type of simultaneous inequality:

- Compound inequality:  a < b < c
- Equivalent Simultaneous inequality: a < b, b < c
- A Complex Simultaneous Inequality: (x + 5)^2 <= 900, x > 24

Comment: The plural form above surely gets the point across just fine in informal registers (e.g. speech, emails, informal blogs, etc.) even if it might not pass some mathematical editors.